# SalesForce Rest API calls Hourly limit

Tags: salesforce

I have a batch process which makes a lot of rest api calls to upsert SalesForce records. The Rest api calls start failing after a while with below error.
I did check the API limit for my account and, I can confirm I am well within the 24 hour API limits.

Is there an hourly limit to the API calls as well ? I tried searching SalesForce documentation ,but everywhere I just see a mention about 24 hour limits.I could not find any limit on each hour basis.

```
{
  “errorCode”: “REQUEST_LIMIT_EXCEEDED”,
  “message”: “You have reached the Connect API’s hourly request limit for this user and application.  Please try again later.”
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't hit the Salesforce API limit, which is generally quite high. You've hit the limit for the [Chatter REST API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.chatterapi.meta/chatterapi/intro_rate_limits.htm), also known as the Connect API. This API has a per user, per application, per hour request limit:

> Chatter REST API requests are subject to rate limiting. Chatter REST API has a different rate limit than other Salesforce APIs. Chatter REST API has a per user, per application, per hour rate limit. When you exceed the rate limit, all Chatter REST API resources return a 503 Service Unavailable error code.

The linked document has a number of recommendations for avoiding this rate limit:

> - If you hit limits when running tests, use multiple users to simulate a real-world scenario.
> - When polling for feed updates, do not exceed one poll per minute (60 polls per hour). To return more results in 1 request, increase the page size.
> - When polling for private messages, do not exceed 60 polls per hour.
> - To avoid making multiple requests, cache metered static assets such as file and dashboard renditions (group and user profile pictures are not metered).
> - Each developer on a team should set up 2 connected apps: one for automated testing and one for manual testing and development. Don’t share connected apps with other developers.
> - Use a unique connected app for the production environment.
> - Don’t share connected apps between applications.

Review the list of [Chatter REST API resources](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.chatterapi.meta/chatterapi/connect_resources_overview.htm) to determine what you're calling that is subject to these enhanced limits.

Comment: Thank you @David Reed for your answer.Think this makes sense.To confirm I am trying to find if I am using the Chatter Rest API or normal Rest APIs .How do I find it in Salesforce?